# Trying to do sliding window

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to print like sliding window way. I could not make it right. So, while the sliding for window size 1, it should print every element. When the sliding window is 2, it should print two consecutive elements.

```
0
1
2

01
12

0123
```

Please check this code:

```
for(int w = 1; w <= a.length; w++) {    
    System.out.println("Window size : " + w);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i; j < w; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int w = 1; w <= a.length; w++){ 
    System.out.println("Window size : " + w);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - w + 1; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < i + w; j++){
                System.out.print(a[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. You have not calculated the no. of windows will be appeared for a specific window size.
2. When you are printing the values of that window you have given the condition that j less than w. It loops for window size times or w times. So, for the window size 1, it will only print 1 element of window size 1. For window size 2 it will print 2 elements of window size 2. But there are also other elements.

Code for your pattern :

```
public class WindowPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* array of elements */
        int[] a = {0,1,2,3};
        /* window size w */
        for(int w = 1; w <= a.length; w++) { 
            System.out.println("Window size : " + w);
            /* No of elements shown of window size (n) = a.length-w+1 */
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length-w+1; i++) {
                for(int j = i; j < w+i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(a[j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer and given the points where he did wrong.